# how i can make batch file in windows read the output of somthing from unix bash file?

Tags: windows, unix, bash, batch-file, copy

i want to make incremntal backup for `repository` by the following command :-
`svnadmin dump myrepos --revision 1001:2000 --incremental > dumpfile2` 
but i want to copy the output on windows box as following :-
`svnadmin dump myrepos --revision 1001:2000 --incremental > file_in_windows_box`

how i can do it ??? 
i can copy directly to window or may be i must creat batch file in windows to read it from stream ... how i can do it ????
i want to copy the output of svnadmin to windows directly without store it in unix because i have a limit size in linux server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to mount the Windows disk on your Unix filesystem. First, share the disk or folder you want to use in Windows (right-click on it). Then as root on Linux:

```
mkdir /windows
mount -t smbfs -o username=username,password=password //windowspc/sharename /windows
```

Use your Windows username, password, the name of your Windows PC and the share name you created. Then you could quite literally do

```
svnadmin dump myrepos --revision 1001:2000 --incremental > /windows/file_in_windows_box
```

Comment: how i can install it to my unix server .... i can do it by command line ? what is the command i can by it install samba to unix

Comment: It will depend on exactly which Unix you are using. For example on my Debian Linux, the command is "apt-get install samba".

Comment: Can you see the Windows PC from the Linux box? Is there a firewall or anything between them? Do you have DNS properly configured? You will need to speak to your sysadmin.

Comment: Wait, you need to put in YOUR OWN username, password, the name of your actual Windows PC etc etc. Like if my username is gaius I would say username=gaius

Comment: ok thanks i do it and it is share the folder but when i execute `svnadmin dump myrepos --revision 1001:2000 --incremental > /windows/file_in_wind` the following error appear `/windows/file_in_wind : Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

The redirection works on the same machine.

If you want to copy the file over the network to another machine, you need to have some server installed on the windows (destination) machine.

For example, you need to have an FTP server. Then, you can use an ftp client to copy the file.